# Inserting images to table ID location in python

Tags: python

I am trying to insert images to table ID location.
my script is creating the folders according to ID but not inserting images to the location. I am very much new to python, its really hard for me to find out any error.

[image]

[image]

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os, sys
from re import split
import time
import datetime
from mydb import cursor
from twisted.enterprise import util as dbutil
from MySQLdb import escape_string
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO

fullfilename = sys.argv[1]
tmp = split('/', fullfilename)
filename = tmp[-1]

tmp = split('_', filename)

tmp2 = split('-', tmp[0])
vrm = tmp2[0]
try:
    nationality = tmp2[1]
except:
    nationality = "ENG"

cameraName = tmp[1]

myDate = tmp[2]
(myYear, myMonth, myDay) = split('-', tmp[2])

tmp2 = split('\.', tmp[3])
(myHour, myMin, mySec, milliSecs) = split('-', tmp2[0])
datetimeObj = datetime.datetime(int(myYear), int(myMonth), int(myDay), int(myHour), int(myMin), int(mySec))

dateTime = datetimeObj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
myTime = datetimeObj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

sql = """SELECT id FROM inteliviz.cameras WHERE camera_name="%s" """ % cameraName
cursor.execute(sql)
tmp = cursor.fetchone()
camId = tmp[0]

# Check to see if we already have the image...
tableName = "customer_1.%s_anpr_vega" % cameraName
sql = """SELECT id FROM %s WHERE plate="%s" AND datetime = "%s" """ % (tableName, vrm, dateTime)
retVal = cursor.execute(sql)
if (retVal == 0):
    sql = """INSERT INTO %s (camera_id, name, plate, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s); """ % (tableName,
        dbutil.quote(camId, "int"),
        dbutil.quote(cameraName, "text"),
        dbutil.quote(vrm,"text"),
        dbutil.quote(dateTime,"text"),
        dbutil.quote(milliSecs,"int"),
        dbutil.quote(nationality,"text"),
        dbutil.quote(filename, "text"))
    cursor.execute(sql)

    sql = """SELECT id FROM %s ORDER BY id DESC""" % tableName
    cursor.execute(sql)
    tmp = cursor.fetchone()
    myId = tmp[0]

    sql = """UPDATE %s SET image=LOAD_FILE('%s') WHERE id = "%s";""" % (tableName,
        fullfilename,
        myId)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

If LOAD_FILE returns NULL it can be one of issues:

```
 - you have not the FILE privilege;
 - file not readable by all;
 - size more than max_allowed_packet bytes
```

For more details look at [MySql string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file).